Pros and cons of displaying users' permissions
I'm working on research around building out an RBAC system for a cloud platform. We're considering displaying the permissions associated with the role(s) a user is assigned on their account settings page.
To clarify, team admins create, assign, and manage roles for their team members, and they would be able to see this info at any time, so with this question I'm just referring to displaying a non-admin users' own permissions.
The benefits we see are around transparency and trust as well as more efficient troubleshooting (ex. they'll know to reach out to a team admin if they think they should have a certain permission, better understand why they can perform a certain action in project A but not project B, etc). On the flip side there is potential for users losing trust if permissions seem excessive or are confusing. I'm also curious if there could be concerns related to security or from the perspective of account admins. Does anyone have insight into the potential risks here?
I've found plenty on disabled / hidden states and permission related error messaging,  but not much around how much info users can see about their permissions. Is displaying permissions something you've seen on any services you use or are familiar with?

The "most complex" permission matrices I know from "publicly accessbile sites" are those allowing settings for notification in different channels. They show up like:
                 Email SMS   Site Inbox
Advertisements:  [x]   [x]   [x]
Events:          [ ]   [ ]   [ ]
Bugfixes:        [ ]   [ ]   [ ]
etc.

And the list can be long.
Regarding security issues there is no general solution. It is dependent on the context. For example, if project A is considered a "secret project" and having permission gives away that a user is involved in that, this would be a problem to tackle seperately.
In a normal case scenario: If a user has some kind of personal login and a personal account page where to lookup the permissions, this is very beneficial from a UX standpoint. It serves the retrieval of information. The UI supports in this regard. It helps troubleshooting as you said.
Concerning high amounts of permissions which might get unmanageable there are lots of possibilities to put structure into this for the user side. One major thing is permission groups. Like for example:
General          terminal login, print, cloud access, email, ...

Project A        repository, wiki, wiki admin, build pipeline admin, ...
(joined xx.yy.2024) 

Project B        repository, wiki ...
(joined xx.yy.2014)

If the join date of a project (and maybe other useful meta-data like "project leader" etc) is tracked, you can filter out unnecessary projects after some time. Better yet, provide filtering options to the user.
Grouping by project is only one example. You also can form other categories. Or grant "Super permissions" something like: Automatic repository access in any project to join in for example.
From an account manager point of view: "Normally" they grant permissions by directly manipulating a database. This can be tedious at times, but they are used to it. If this process can be streamlined so that a project leader themself can add members and permission groups by some pre-defined templates ("developer", "QA", "externals", "whatever") and therefore taking off load from the DB admins ("account managers") this would surely be a great step forward.
